# youtube video cannot played in my webview application?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have created one web-view Application in android , the Web-view Loaded Successfully but video is not able to play, how can I fix this kind of problem , when I played video, audio only heard.

```
public class ZudiozFragment extends Fragment {
WebView webView;
private ProgressBar bar;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_zudioz, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);        
    webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    bar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);       
    new ProgressTask().execute();                                                   
    return rootView;
}
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    return null;                  
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                                          
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());          
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.loadUrl("http://ebltv.com");

        bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// fix for loading youtube videos.

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
} else {
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
}
```

Comment: setPluginsEnabled its contain error.. it was ask change to setPluginState

Comment: setPluginsEnabled needed for api level below 8, so just ignore that case if you not needed